# 95 Integra right rear window 'off-track'

Tags: power-windows, integra

The regulation mechanism that keeps the window 'on-track' and limits the travel does not function correctly.  [Is this the correct part (eBay, because I can not find a new one online)](https://www.ebay.com/itm/R-R-Right-Passenger-Rear-Window-Regulator-Electric-Sedan-94-01-INTEGRA-S-151RM/401674813378?hash=item5d85af3fc2:g:v74AAOSwkvtcJm0W:rk:2:pf:0) to remedy the issue?

I believe the required [Part Number is 72711-ST8-003](https://www.team-integra.net/forum/11-generation-three/341418-part-search-methods.html#post2030076464) as [shown in the diagram](https://www.acurapartswarehouse.com/oem/acura~regulator~r~rr~door~power~72711-st8-003.html?Make=Acura&Model=Integra&Year=1995&Submodel=&Filter=(bt=1%2C8;et=1%2C4)), indicating the part is discontinued / unavailable new.

If you have replaced this item in an Acura Integra (especially 4-door rear window), please state this in your reply and any `lessons learned`.  Thank you

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted your local auto parts store to see if they offer a replacement?

Comment: Not yet.  Maybe I should ask the dealer how they would handle this